# Set user variable in jdbc url

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need to specify a custom variable when connecting to MySQL via JDBC from Java code. The session variables can be set like this:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://xxxx.xx.xx.xx/dbName?sessionVariables=group_concat_max_len=204800
```

Like this doesn't work:

```
 jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://xxxx.xx.xx.xx/dbName?userVariables=UserId=1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html.

There is no reference in this source to custom variable. I'm not sure it's possible to specify a custom variable when connecting to MySQL using hibernate.

My idea:

Why not create a servlet (which of course has the URL ability to contain a custom variable) with user variable instead?